# lmer interpretation of correlation

Tags: anova, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

I have the following output:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML 
Formula: Value ~ Group + (1 | Koralle) 
   Data: dat
  AIC  BIC logLik deviance REMLdev
 5988 6008  -2990     5985    5980
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Koralle  (Intercept)  4.1737  2.0430  
 Residual             15.4811  3.9346  
Number of obs: 1070, groups: Koralle, 5

Fixed effects:
                Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)       10.463      1.468   7.127
GroupTreatment    -1.071      1.895  -0.565

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr)
GroupTrtmnt -0.775
```

I am not sure how to interprete the -0.775 from the Correlation of the Fixed Effects. I even don't know which correlation this is? Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Correlation of Fixed Effects:` refers to the estimated correlation between the fixed-effect parameters `(Intercept)` and `GroupTreatment`*. Usually these correlations arise when the data is not centered.

You can center continuous data by subtracting the mean. This will avoid slope-intercept correlations and thus make the interpretation of main effects more straight forward in cases where the data range is far away from zero. E.g. a main effect of gender when a model is fit to heights measured across ages would indicate a height difference at age 0. Centering age at a particular value will allow to test for gender differences at a particular age.

In your example you presumably have a factor `Group` with two levels `Treatment` and `NoTreatment`. Here centering might make less sense, because there is no group with `HalfTreatment`. This factor level might even be impossible. Thus you do not need to worry about the slope-intercept correlation.

*edited to incorporate Ben Bolker's correction

Comment: Okay thank you! Is this correlation the pearson correlation? Or in other words can I calculate this correlation without making a LMM? For example with `cor(dat$Group, dat$Koralle, method="pearson")` or something similar?

Comment: This is generally a good, useful answer, but your first sentence is wrong:  This is not the correlation among random effects (the random effects in this model are assumed to be independent), but rather the estimated correlation between the *fixed-effect parameters* `(Intercept)` and `GroupTreatment` (abbreviated as necessary).